# Installing Nvidia Omniverse Launcher

Tags: nvidia, omniverse

I have a problem installing Nvidia Omniverse launcher.
I watched all the possible and imaginable tutorials to understand how to install it, but each of these tutorials installs it in a different way.

My problem lies in simply understanding how to fill out the installation form on the site which appears to me as follows in the photo:

[Form image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW3TQ.png)

[Form image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlxSF.png)

[Form image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pusdu.png)

I don't understand why it appears half in English and half not, besides the fact that google translator can't translate it where it's not in English or translates it badly.
In any case, after being able to translate it and compile it by pressing the "Submit" button, absolutely nothing happens, it just sends me back to the installation plan selection screen.

Specifically I'm trying to install the standard license.

Sorry, maybe I'm doing it all wrong, but I really don't understand how to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you must choose the language to English. For reference I am sharing my form screenshot so that you can compare and fill. Form 3 is nothing but you have to tick the checkbox if you need and subscription mails. First box is for buisness related update mails second is for technical updates[image: form1]